# Recommendations for generating NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

Does anyone have any recommendations of Visual Studio extensions that can be used to add projects to a solution that generate a NuGet package.  Ideally, we would like something where we could tell it the relative path of the contents, and one that supports pushing symbol files as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [NuGet Packager Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/daf5c6db-386b-4994-bdd7-b6cd52f11b72) created by Ove Anderson.